# Drag and drop in AngularJS: make a directive that is a drop zone, showing an overlay when dragging

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, drag-and-drop

## What I want to achieve

Create a directive, let's call it dropZone, in which I can put some html (e.g. a form). When the user drags a file into the web page, I want to show an overlay over the content of dropZone, just like in Gmail. That overlay should, of course, disappear when the user isn't dragging a file anymore.

[image: Drop file Gmail]

I also want to be able to detect the drop event on the directive to handle the file.

## What I've tried so far

I've tried to create a directive that uses this template :

```
template: '<div>' + 
        '<div id="drop-zone-overlay" class="drop-zone-overlay">' +
            '<h1>Drop files here</h1>' + 
        '</div>' +
        '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' + 
      '</div>',
```

And this CSS:

```
.drop-zone-overlay {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    background: rgba(#60a7dc, .8);
    border: 5px dashed #60a7dc;
}
```

Please see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5162/) for full example.

---

The part I'm struggling with is to make the overlay "float" over all the html content of the directive. Any idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to achieve it with this HTML code for the template:

```
template: '<div class="drop-zone-container">' + 
        '<div id="drop-zone-overlay" class="drop-zone-overlay">' +
            '<div class="drop-zone-overlay-text">Drop files here</div>' + 
        '</div>' +
        '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' + 
      '</div>'
```

And this CSS:

```
.drop-zone-container {
  position: relative;
}

.drop-zone-overlay {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 99999;
    background: rgba(#60a7dc, .8);
    border: 5px dashed #60a7dc;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.drop-zone-overlay::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

.drop-zone-overlay-text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2.8em;
  color: #60a7dc;
}
```

Please see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5183/) for full example.